# Error loading new emacsclient frame

Tags: frames, emacsclient

Recently I was looking for run emacs as daemon in linux, whats give me the oportunity to use org-carture from everywhere in the sistem for example. My first aproach was start it in the init.el file, but the I discover that I can run emacs --daemon in my sistem init, but there is a problem. when I try to exec: `emacsclient -ne "(make-capture-frame)"` which open a new frame directly in org-capture I get an error: `*ERROR*: Unknown terminal type`, but if I irun server from an emacs instance and not an emacsclient, The function works well so I cant find my mistake.

Anyone knows what it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend just making emacsclient start the daemon on demand, using `emacsclient --alternate-editor=""`. That way you can exit or crash emacs, and the emacsclient-using scripts or aliases will just start it again when needed.